# Why does this Google Sheets formula for the last non-empty cell in a column work?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I was looking for a solution to find the last non-empty cell in a column.

I found the following solution at [Google Docs Editor Help](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8883630?hl=en)

`INDEX(C:C;MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>""))`

This solution works perfectly fine and even works withe empty cells and headers - but I can't figure out how it works. I tried to analyse the suggestion by cutting it up into its parts and looking at the return values separately - but then I couldn't reproduce the desired results.

Can somebody explain what's happening? I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(C:C))
```

will output row numbers like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C:C<>"")
```

will output `TRUE` if cells in C column are not empty (otherwise) `FALSE`

```
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
...
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>""))
```

will do this (note that `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0` in PC logic)

```
1   ×   TRUE    =     1     
2   ×   TRUE    =     2
3   ×   TRUE    =     3
4   ×   FALSE   =     0
5   ×   TRUE    =     5
6   ×   FALSE   =     0
7   ×   FALSE   =     0
... ×   ...     =     ...
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")))
```

will output the highest number so in this case:

```
5
```

---

now `INDEX` is type of `ARRAYFORMULA` so this will work too:

```
 =INDEX(MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")))
```

---

now we move `MAX(...)` part into 2nd `INDEX` argument which stands for row and as 1st argument we enter our range we want to map:

```
=INDEX(C:C, MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")))
```

this translates to:

```
=INDEX(C:C, 5)
```

which means: "return cell on 5th row in C column"

---

to answer your question why `=ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")` returns only single value - its because there is no command to process array so basically this is equal to:

```
=ROW(C1)*(C1<>"")
```

and result can be 0 or 1 - depends on if arguments are

```
TRUE   ×  TRUE    =  1
TRUE   ×  FALSE   =  0
FALSE  ×  TRUE    =  0
FALSE  ×  FALSE   =  0
```

and wrapping that into `MAX` is like having

```
=MAX(1)
```

or:

```
=MAX(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `C:C<>""` returns `TRUE` if a cell is non-empty, which is converted into `1` when doing arithmetic with it. Similarly, it returns `FALSE` or 0 when it's empty.
2. Then, it's multiplied by `ROW(C:C)`, so every empty cell will result in 0, and every non-empty cell in a value equal to its row number.
3. Take the maximum value of that, which is the row number (call it *X*) of the last non-empty row.
4. Now we use [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) to find the value of the *X*-th row in column C.

It's indeed a bit strange that things like `=MAX(ROW(C:C))` on their own produce 1. I don't have an explicit explanation for this, but I think this is Google Sheets automatically expanding certain formulas over arrays, as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), because of using `INDEX`:

> Many array formulas will be automatically expanded into neighboring cells, obviating the explicit use of `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: Everything you write seems logical, but why does `=MAX(ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>"")` or `ROW(C:C)*(C:C<>""` on its own always return 0?